# Better adhesive for LED light strips?

Tags: lighting, led, cabinets, adhesive, custom-cabinetry

I just got new cabinets and am going to be installing LED light strips on the under-sides of the shelves for effect.

My experience with these strips in the past is that the adhesive backing is not very strong and wears out after a few months despite it having the 3M label.  I would like these installed well the first time, so that I do not have to mess with the cabinet lighting again for decades if possible.

I've considered adding a dab of super glue to points along the strip, but then I worry if I have to replace these in 10 years, I won't be able to remove the old strips.  On the other hand, I've considered a bead of silicone because it's clear and can easily be removed with a scraper.

What may be other options for fix the LED strips in place, other than super-glue? I need them to be fixed well enough in place to last years, but also for me to be able to remove them if necessary without ruining the shelves.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer board, not a general discussion forum. Unfortunately, you question, while valid, falls more into a broad general discussion/shopping recommendation category and neither of those are on topic here. That said, you may want to consider using screws - their "adhesive" doesn't wear out, and they make removal/reinstallation very easy.

Comment: This is not a very good suggestion, considering screws would penetrate the circuitry internal to the light strip and short it out.

Answer (score 1):

Strengthen the supplied sticky backing with something better at all stress points (beginning, end, change of direction, near any switches or other places the strip will be handled).

Options:

- double sided foam tape
- A bracket made of a strip of wood with wood glue and/or screws
- A metal bracket ... just a thin strip of metal that runs across the light strip and is screwed into the underside of the cabinet tightly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I might consider the double sided foam tape.  The bracketing suggestions, while technically sound, would cheapen the look of the cabinet.  Great suggestion though if I were installing these in my shop.

Comment: The tape is probably easiest but if you are looking for good looking, rather than the crude brackets I pictured, look at woodworking or furniture / hobby supply for similar things that are designed to be attractive.  There are shiny brass ones, ornate bronze ones, etc etc.